# Strict mode error only in IE11. Can I take off strict mode just for this browser?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11

I get the error *`Assignment to read-only properties is not allowed in strict mode'* on this line of my code:

```
wrapper.style = 'transition: transform 3s;';
```

This is a chunk of the function it's in:

```
'use strict';
function work() {
  var wrapper = document.getElementById( 'wrp' ),
  infoPage = document.getElementById( 'i-pg' ),
  body = document.getElementById( 'body' ),

  carA = document.getElementById( 'car-a' ),
  keyA = document.getElementById( 'key-a' ),
  manualA = document.getElementById( 'manual-a' ),
  wheelA = document.getElementById( 'wheel-a' );

  if( this.id === 'info' ) {
    wrapper.style = 'transition: transform 3s;'; //PROBLEM LINE
    wrapper.classList.add( 'up' );
    body.classList.add( 'dark' );
    infoPage.classList.remove( 'down' );
  }
}
```

This code works perfectly in all modern browsers i've tested. Only in IE11 is this breaking the entire site, stopping all subsequent lines from running.

If I take out the first line: `'use strict';` everything works fine.
Is there a simple fix while keeping strict mode on? Or just target IE11 and somehow remove strict mode for that browser?

There might be a better approach.

Comment: can you try this wrapper['style'] = 'transition: transform 3s;';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not fix it, instead of ignoring the error?

```
wrapper.style.transition = 'transform 3s;';
```

Comment: The way in my original code works in all modern browsers. However is my code at fault here or IE11?

Comment: That's because most modern browsers [have a workaround built in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style#Setting_style). Technically, the `style` property returns a [`CSSStyleDeclaration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration) and is read-only.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might get an errror cause you're trying to assign a `transform 3s` to style property, while actually you should assign it to a transition property.
Like this: wrapper.style.transition = 'transform 3s';

Answer (score 0):

Checkout:

https://devtidbits.com/2016/06/12/assignment-to-read-only-properties-is-not-allowed-in-strict-mode/#comment-1611

Apparently you're supposed to use this something like

```
myEle.style.cssText = "color: red;" // or
myEle.setAttribute("class", "myClass"); // Multiple style properties
//For newly created style sheet objects, you must first append the element to the document before you can set cssText.
```

However I still get the same error even after applying that fix...